# Do the different rules generated by booktabs have the same thickness?

Tags: rules, viewers, booktabs

I use the `booktabs` package and `excel2latex` to generate my tables. I work in TeXmaker. As I zoom in or zoom out on my table, I find that, sometimes the `\toprule`, sometimes `\midrule` and sometimes the `\bottomrule` appear to be wider than other lines. On the other hand, when I print such a table, the top and bottom rule are wider while the mid rule is thinner.

Is it normal? I like the printed looks of my table but I don't want it to randomly change if I decide to print the whole thesis.

Here is my code and examples:

```
% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Tabelle3'
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{rrr}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{Anzahl der Kanäle} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Streifenbreite in [mm]} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Kanalbreite in [mm]} \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{n} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{c} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{b} \\
    5     & 13    & 2,80  \\
    6     & 11    & 2,50  \\
    7     & 9     & 2,86  \\
    8     & 8     & 2,50  \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
```

[image: All lines equal]
[image: Bottom line wider]
[image: Top line wider]

Comment: `\toprule` and `\bottomrule` are equally thick and both are thicker than `\midrule`.

Comment: the specified widths are as Harish Kumar states note however that a pdf viewer has to snap the rules to pixel boundaries so (depending on the resolution of your display, and your pdf viewer) you may see the width of the line change by one or two pixels as you zoom in or out or just scroll the document, if the line is one pixel wide and you position it exactly on a pixel boundary it may appear as 1 or 2 pixels wide depending on the viewer's rules.

Comment: In case you want to modify the thickness try `\heavyrulewidth=2pt` and `\lightrulewidth=2pt`. But sometimes the pdf-viewer plays you tricks, and they seem to be of different thickness.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your PDF viewer is playing tricks on you. See [David's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163599/are-booktabs-generated-lines-equally-wide#comment375284_163599). In fact, by default, `\toprule` and `\bottomrule` produce a rule slightly thicker than that produced by `\midrule`.

If you don't trust me (or your eyes), you can always check this for yourself by printing the values of the relevant thickness macros in your document. According to section 3 of the [`booktabs`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) documentation,

> The rule commands here all take a default which may be reset within
>   the document (preferably, but not necessarily, in the preamble). For
>   the top and bottom rules this default is `\heavyrulewidth` and for
>   midrules it is `\lightrulewidth` [...]

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\bgroup
\ttfamily
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\string\toprule\ \& \string\bottomrule\ thickness & \the\heavyrulewidth\\
\string\midrule\ thickness                        & \the\lightrulewidth
\end{tabular}
\egroup

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{rrr}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{Anzahl der Kanäle} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Streifenbreite in [mm]} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Kanalbreite in [mm]} \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{n} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{c} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{b} \\
    5     & 13    & 2,80  \\
    6     & 11    & 2,50  \\
    7     & 9     & 2,86  \\
    8     & 8     & 2,50  \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's a precise choice by the author of `booktabs`: the rules produced by `\toprule` and `\bottomrule`, besides applying different vertical spacing, have different thickness than those produced by `\midrule`.

I use “thickness” where the package author would use “width” in order not to make confusion with the horizontal extent of the rules which is the same for `\toprule`, `\midrule` and `\bottomrule`.

The top and bottom rules are used to clearly separate the table from the context, so they are drawn a bit thicker. You can modify the setup by giving different values to some parameters; here are the defaults

```
\setlength{\heavyrulewidth}{0.08em}
\setlength{\lightrulewidth}{0.05em}
\setlength{\cmidrulewidth}{0.03em}
```

The `em` is computed at package loading, which is possibly a bad choice; it would have been better to delay this setting `\AtBeginDocument`, which is executed after `\normalfont` has been issued.

The `\heavyrulewidth` is used for `\toprule` and `\bottomrule`, while `\lightrulewidth` is used for `\midrule`. For `\cmidrule` the third parameter is used, which is slightly less than `\lightrulewidth`.

Don't trust PDF viewers at low resolutions when comparing rule thicknesses: pixel adjustments can make different rules look alike or conversely.

Comment: Any idea why `\cmidrulewidth` is smaller than `\lightrulewidth`?

Comment: @daleif `\cmidrule` is not the same as `\midrule` that separates distinct parts of the table from each other; `\cmidrule` is a “local separator”.

Comment: but can anyone actually see the difference visually? ;-)