# my toprule and bottomrule width are different?

Tags: tables, width, line

I may have change something before at the macro level by accident with some code I got online. How could I set it back?

Now I am facing this problem where when I put:
\setlength\heavyrulewidth{0.14em}
\setlength\lightrulewidth{0.14em}

to get same thickness on  all lines,

I got the bottom like thicker than the top line???

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\setlength{\pdfpagewidth}{8.5in} 
\setlength{\pdfpageheight}{11in}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{colortbl} 
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,array}
\usepackage{siunitx} % don't use 'detect-all' switch unless you know what you're doing
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating} % for 'sidewaystable' env.

\setlength\heavyrulewidth{0.14em}
\setlength\lightrulewidth{0.14em}

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\sisetup{
  input-symbols         = (),
  table-format          = -1.3,
  table-space-text-post = ***,
  table-align-text-post = false,
  group-digits          = false
}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{}l *{8}{S} @{}} 
\arrayrulecolor{blue} 
\toprule
          & {(1)} & {(2)} & {(3)} & {(4)} & {(5)} & {(6)} & {(7)} & {(8)} \\
Variables & {FullD} & {FullD} & {FullD} & {FullD} & {FullD} & {FullD} & {FullD} & {FullD} \\ 
\midrule
STI\_30   & 0.301*** & 0.179** & 0.152* & 0.159 & -0.000 & 0.107 & 0.097 & 0.115 \\
          & (0.087) & (0.085) & (0.085) & (0.097) & (0.003) & (0.084) & (0.094) & (0.105) \\
Produce\_Full\_SR &  & 0.349*** & 0.321*** & 0.303* & 0.318*** & 0.270*** & 0.244*** & 0.257*** \\
          &  & (0.071) & (0.074) & (0.170) & (0.074) & (0.074) & (0.078) & (0.090) \\
Has\_Sus\_Efforts &  &  & 0.078*** & 0.077*** & 0.245*** & 0.001 & 0.046** & 0.129*** \\
          &  &  & (0.020) & (0.020) & (0.094) & (0.013) & (0.019) & (0.041) \\
1o.STI\_30\#1o.Produce\_Full\_SR &  &  &  & 0.000 &  &  &  &  \\
          &  &  &  & (0.000) &  &  &  &  \\
1o.STI\_30\#1o.Has\_Sus\_Efforts &  &  &  &  & 0.000 &  &  &  \\
          &  &  &  &  & (0.000) &  &  &  \\
Water\_Efforts &  &  &  &  &  & 0.168*** &  &  \\
          &  &  &  &  &  & (0.039) &  &  \\
C\_or\_S  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 0.202*** &  \\
          &  &  &  &  &  &  & (0.066) &  \\
C\_or\_S1 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 0.221** \\
          &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & (0.100) \\
Constant  & 0.054*** & 0.029*** & -0.001 & -0.002 & 0.000 & -0.001 & 0.000 & 0.000 \\
          & (0.010) & (0.008) & (0.003) & (0.003) & (0.003) & (0.003) & (0.000) & (0.000) \\
\midrule
Observations & {566} & {555} & {552} & {552} & {552} & {552} & {252} & {140} \\
Year FE      & {No} & {No} & {No} & {No} & {No} & {No} & {No} & {No} \\
No.\ of obs  & {566} & {555} & {552} & {552} & {552} & {552} & {252} & {140} \\
Adjusted\ R\textsuperscript{2} & {0.0696} & {0.211} & {0.233} & {0.232} & {0.234} & {0.275} & {0.199} & {0.133} \\ 
\bottomrule
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{9}{c}{Robust standard errors in parentheses} \\
\multicolumn{9}{c}{$^{***}\ p<0.01$; $^{**}\ p<0.05$; $^{*}\ p<0.1$} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Thx for the help^^

Johnny

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Also check with a different pdf viewer and/or zoom level. Sometimes the width of rules is shown incorrectly by the pdf viewer.

Comment: HI samcarter i added the code ^^

Comment: I checked and the width are really different at the naked eye level, though they looked the same when zoomed in @.@

Comment: Thanks for adding the code! I get the same line widths if I test it.

Comment: I think this is probably a problem of the pdf viewer and your latex code works fine.

Comment: Ah i see... but i wanted to screenshot the table and it looks different from the outset. Do u have any idea how to set it at the macro level??

Comment: I can see some variations depending on zoom level, so I agree with samcarter, this is likely to be rounding issues in the PDF viewer

Comment: samecarter which viewer do u use? perhaps I should just change my viewer lol... I am using texworks

Comment: @Johnny I tested with the build-in viewer of texstudio and mac preview. many pdf viewer have some preferences to switch off options like "enhance thin lines" or similar. Switching these off might help but other things might look less good then.

Comment: @Johnny In case you are also using cmidrules, don't forget to change their width as well: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/163604/36296

Comment: @samcarter - The OP faithfully copied the code from my earlier answer into the new query...

Comment: @Mico Oh, I did not see the `\sisetup{...}` within the document and though the table-format etc would be missing. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution with \patchcmd:

just add the following into the code =) Thanks for the help guys anyway^^

```
\usepackage{booktabs, etoolbox}

\newlength{\toprulewidth}
\setlength{\toprulewidth}{0.14em}
\patchcmd{\toprule}% <cmd>
  {\heavyrulewidth}{\toprulewidth}% <search><replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\patchcmd{\bottomrule}% <cmd>
  {\heavyrulewidth}{\toprulewidth}% <search><replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
```

Comment: but it works only if we don't set the lightrulewidth to the same value--when the problem persists =( guess it's something to do with the viewer software

Comment: Your entire answer can be simplified to `\setlength\heavyrulewidth{0.14em}`. (The default value is `0.08em`.) Do check it out for yourself.

Comment: Regarding the claim you posted in a comment: Why would you -- or anyone else -- set `\heavyrulewidth` equal to `\lightrulewidth` to begin with? That would defeat the whole purpose of creating a professional-looking table...