# Overfull \hbox (3.8889pt too wide) detected

Tags: tables, siunitx

my code: what's wrong guys?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\setlength{\pdfpagewidth}{8.5in} 
\setlength{\pdfpageheight}{11in}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{colortbl} 
\usepackage{array}


\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,array}
\usepackage{siunitx} % don't use 'detect-all' switch unless you know what you're doing
\usepackage{booktabs, etoolbox}
\usepackage{rotating} % for 'sidewaystable' env.

\newlength{\toprulewidth}
\setlength{\toprulewidth}{0.14em}
\patchcmd{\toprule}% <cmd>
{\heavyrulewidth}{\toprulewidth}% <search><replace>
{}{}% <success><failure>
\patchcmd{\bottomrule}% <cmd>
{\heavyrulewidth}{\toprulewidth}% <search><replace>
{}{}% <success><failure>


\newlength{\midrulewidth}
\setlength{\midrulewidth}{0.1em}
\patchcmd{\midrule}% <cmd>
{\lightrulewidth}{\midrulewidth}% <search><replace>
{}{}% <success><failure>


%\setlength\heavyrulewidth{0.14em}
%\setlength\lightrulewidth{0.1em}
%\setlength{\cmidrulewidth}{0.06em}

\begin{document}
    %\begin{figure}
    %\begin{adjustwidth}{-3cm}{}

    %\begin{sidewaystable}
    \sisetup{
        input-symbols         = (),
        table-format          = -1.3,
        table-space-text-post = ***,
        table-align-text-post = false,
        group-digits          = false
    }
    \noindent
    \hspace*{-2.2cm}\begin{tabular}{@{}l *{8}{S} @{}} 
        \arrayrulecolor{blue} 
        \toprule
        & {(1)} & {(2)} & {(3)} & {(4)} & {(5)} & {(6)} & {(7)} & {(8)} \\
        Variables & {EmiD} & {EmiD} & {EmiD} & {EmiD} & {EmiD} & {EmiD} & {EmiD} & {EmiD} \\ 
        \midrule
STI\_30 & 0.359*** & 0.237** & 0.226** & 0.220* & 0.220* & 0.144 & 0.096 & 0.103 \\
 & (0.098) & (0.094) & (0.095) & (0.125) & (0.125) & (0.120) & (0.117) & (0.152) \\
Produce\_Full\_SR &  & 0.411*** & 0.423*** & 0.436** & 0.436** & 0.390** & 0.350** & 0.313* \\
 &  & (0.077) & (0.078) & (0.170) & (0.170) & (0.167) & (0.166) & (0.175) \\
Has\_Sus\_Efforts &  &  & 0.099 & 0.099 & 0.099 & -0.024 &  &  \\
 &  &  & (0.070) & (0.070) & (0.070) & (0.069) &  &  \\
1o.STI\_30\#1o.Produce\_Full\_SR &  &  &  & 0.000 & 0.000 & 0.000 & 0.000 & 0.000 \\
 &  &  &  & (0.000) & (0.000) & (0.000) & (0.000) & (0.000) \\
1o.STI\_30\#1o.Has\_Sus\_Efforts &  &  &  &  & 0.000 & 0.000 & 0.000 & 0.000 \\
 &  &  &  &  & (0.000) & (0.000) & (0.000) & (0.000) \\
Water\_Efforts &  &  &  &  &  & 0.230*** & 0.202*** &  \\
 &  &  &  &  &  & (0.046) & (0.047) &  \\
C\_or\_S &  &  &  &  &  &  & 0.145** & 0.156* \\
 &  &  &  &  &  &  & (0.072) & (0.092) \\
C\_or\_S1 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 0.209** \\
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & (0.097) \\
Constant & 0.176*** & 0.108*** & 0.014 & 0.015 & 0.015 & 0.029 & -0.002 & 0.158*** \\
 & (0.026) & (0.023) & (0.064) & (0.064) & (0.064) & (0.066) & (0.018) & (0.050) \\
\midrule

Observations & {249} & {249} &{ 248} & {248} & {248} &{ 248} & {237} & {135} \\
Year FE & {No} & {No} & {No} &{ No} &{ No} & {No} & {No} & {No} \\
 Adjusted R-squared &{ 0.0721} & {0.220} &{ 0.225} &{ 0.222} & {0.222} & {0.284} & {0.295} & {0.200} \\ 
\bottomrule
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{9}{c}{Robust standard errors in parentheses} \\
\multicolumn{9}{c}{$^{***}\ p<0.01$; $^{**}\ p<0.05$; $^{*}\ p<0.1$} \\
\end{tabular}
%\end{sidewaystable}
%\end{adjustwidth}
%\end{figure}
```

Comment: how to fix it guys? thx

Comment: Your table is too wide, that's 'wrong' with it ;-)

Comment: You can condense the problem to `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
    \sisetup{
        input-symbols         = (),
        table-format          = -1.3,
        table-space-text-post = ***,
        table-align-text-post = false,
        group-digits          = false
    }

\begin{document}
 \begin{tabular}{S}
 (0.098)\\ 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}` Your table is not too wide, it is a problem with the setup of the S column but I have no idea how to solve it. Increasing the pre and post space does not help.

Comment: The problem is that currently the s column allocates enough room for the "pure" number but not for the `()` around it. Dirty hack and definitly the wrong thing to do: allocate more space by using `table-format = -2.4`

Comment: Change margins of 1in to 1mm and remove `\hspace*{-2.2cm}`. Then fit perfectly ;-) Suggestion: `\footnotesize\centering` to left a decent margin. Question: Are you using R for the statistics? if yes, you should try the `stargazer` package.

Comment: 3.8889 pt is about 1.37 mm. Is it necessary to correct this warning?

Answer (score 3):

- your table is to wide that can be fit in text width
- table can be shrink with two measures:

  - using the following trick

    ```
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
    \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{8}{S} }
    ```
  - using font size `\small`
- even with this you will get warnings like

  ```
  Overfull \hbox (3.5972pt too wide) detected at line 63
  ```

  for each table row, where are numbers in parenthesis.

  these warnings are caused by use of parenthesis around of numbers. apparently they require reservation of digit's space in the definition for `S` column style. if you would increase `table-format` to `-1.4` than these warnings will disappear, but table will become even wider. than you have three choices:

  - further reduce font size, for example to `\scriptsize` (not recommended)
  - use the package `changepage` and for table make locally text width wider (for example for `\marginparwidth`)
  - since this warnings doesn't harm live with these warning and change the `table-format` only from yours `1.3`  to `-1.3`.

consider aforementioned the *mwe* (in which i remove all what is not necessary for show your table) is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{siunitx} % don't use 'detect-all' switch unless you know what you're doing
\usepackage{array, booktabs}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \small
\sisetup{
    input-symbols         = (),
    table-format          = -1.3,
    table-space-text-pre = (,
    table-space-text-post = ***,
    table-align-text-post = false,
    group-digits          = false
    }
    \arrayrulecolor{blue}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
    \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{8}{S} }
    \toprule
            & {(1)}  & {(2)}  & {(3)}  & {(4)}  & {(5)}  & {(6)}  & {(7)}  & {(8)}  \\
Variables   & {EmiD} & {EmiD} & {EmiD} & {EmiD} & {EmiD} & {EmiD} & {EmiD} & {EmiD} \\
    \midrule
STI\_30 & 0.359*** & 0.237** & 0.226** & 0.220*  & 0.220*  & 0.144   & 0.096   & 0.103   \\
        & (0.098)  & (0.094) & (0.095) & (0.125) & (0.125) & (0.120) & (0.117) & (0.152) \\
    \addlinespace
Produce\_Full\_SR
        &  & 0.411*** & 0.423*** & 0.436** & 0.436** & 0.390** & 0.350** & 0.313* \\
        &  & (0.077) & (0.078) & (0.170) & (0.170) & (0.167) & (0.166) & (0.175) \\
    \addlinespace
Has\_Sus\_Efforts
        &  &  & 0.099 & 0.099 & 0.099 & -0.024 &  &  \\
        &  &  & (0.070) & (0.070) & (0.070) & (0.069) &  &  \\
    \addlinespace
1o.STI\_30\#1o.Produce\_Full\_SR
        &  &  &  & 0.000 & 0.000 & 0.000 & 0.000 & 0.000 \\
        &  &  &  & (0.000) & (0.000) & (0.000) & (0.000) & (0.000) \\
    \addlinespace
1o.STI\_30\#1o.Has\_Sus\_Efforts
        &  &  &  &  & 0.000 & 0.000 & 0.000 & 0.000 \\
        &  &  &  &  & (0.000) & (0.000) & (0.000) & (0.000) \\
    \addlinespace
Water\_Efforts
        &  &  &  &  &  & 0.230*** & 0.202*** &  \\
        &  &  &  &  &  & (0.046) & (0.047) &  \\
    \addlinespace
C\_or\_S
        &  &  &  &  &  &  & 0.145** & 0.156* \\
        &  &  &  &  &  &  & (0.072) & (0.092) \\
    \addlinespace
C\_or\_S1
        &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 0.209** \\
        &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & (0.097) \\
    \addlinespace
Constant
        & 0.176*** & 0.108*** & 0.014 & 0.015 & 0.015 & 0.029 & -0.002 & 0.158*** \\
        & (0.026)  & (0.023) & (0.064) & (0.064) & (0.064) & (0.066) & (0.018) & (0.050) \\
    \midrule
Observations
        & {249} & {249} &{ 248} & {248} & {248} &{ 248} & {237} & {135} \\
Year FE & {No} & {No} & {No} &{ No} &{ No} & {No} & {No} & {No} \\
 Adjusted R-squared
        & {0.0721} & {0.220} &{ 0.225} &{ 0.222} & {0.222} & {0.284} & {0.295} & {0.200} \\
    \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\multicolumn{9}{l}{Robust standard errors in parentheses} \\
\multicolumn{9}{l}{$^{***}\ p<0.01$; $^{**}\ p<0.05$; $^{*}\ p<0.1$} \\
\end{tabular*}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

(red lines indicates text borders).

**addendum:**
meanwhile i found the fourth possible solution for your particular case. With dirty trick is possible to  compensate increased table's width when you prescribe four decimal digits, where the forth is for `)`. The trick is to set negative `\tablcolsep`:

```
...
    \begin{figure}
    \small
\sisetup{
    input-symbols         = (),
    table-format          = -1.4,  % <---
    table-space-text-post = ***,
    table-align-text-post = false,
    group-digits          = false
    }
    \arrayrulecolor{blue}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{-3pt} % <---
    \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{8}{S} }
```

...

with it with and `\small` font size the compilation of *mwe* will not complain  about overfull `\hbox` anymore and will give the following result:

[image]

you can observe, that differences between both results are negligible.

Answer (score 1):

The source of the `3.8889pt` overfull boxes are the parenthesis around the numbers in your table. This can be avoided by wrapping them in curly brackets, e.g. `{(}` and `{)}` and adding `table-space-text-pre = (` to the siunitx setup (adjusting the post space is not necessary, because the *** allocate more than enough room).

The code in the following example will still result in 3 overfull boxes, because I decided to remove the space for plus or minus signs from `table-format = 1.3` in favour of having the parenthesis fit exactly around the numbers.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\setlength{\pdfpagewidth}{8.5in} 
\setlength{\pdfpageheight}{11in}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{colortbl} 
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,array}
\usepackage{siunitx} % don't use 'detect-all' switch unless you know what you're doing
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating} % for 'sidewaystable' env.

\setlength\heavyrulewidth{0.14em}
\setlength\lightrulewidth{0.14em}

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\sisetup{
  input-symbols         = (),
  table-format          = 1.3,
  table-space-text-post = ***,
  table-space-text-pre  = (,
  table-align-text-post = false,
  group-digits          = false
}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{}l *{8}{S} @{}} 
\arrayrulecolor{blue} 
\toprule
          & {(1)} & {(2)} & {(3)} & {(4)} & {(5)} & {(6)} & {(7)} & {(8)} \\
Variables & {FullD} & {FullD} & {FullD} & {FullD} & {FullD} & {FullD} & {FullD} & {FullD} \\ 
\midrule
STI\_30   & 0.301*** & 0.179** & 0.152* & 0.159 & -0.000 & 0.107 & 0.097 & 0.115 \\
          & {(}0.087{)} & {(}0.085{)} & {(}0.085{)} & {(}0.097{)} & {(}0.003{)} & {(}0.084{)} & {(}0.094{)} & {(}0.105{)} \\
Produce\_Full\_SR &  & 0.349*** & 0.321*** & 0.303* & 0.318*** & 0.270*** & 0.244*** & 0.257*** \\
          &  & {(}0.071{)} & {(}0.074{)} & {(}0.170{)} & {(}0.074{)} & {(}0.074{)} & {(}0.078{)} & {(}0.090{)} \\
Has\_Sus\_Efforts &  &  & 0.078*** & 0.077*** & 0.245*** & 0.001 & 0.046** & 0.129*** \\
          &  &  & {(}0.020{)} & {(}0.020{)} & {(}0.094{)} & {(}0.013{)} & {(}0.019{)} & {(}0.041{)} \\
1o.STI\_30\#1o.Produce\_Full\_SR &  &  &  & 0.000 &  &  &  &  \\
          &  &  &  & {(}0.000{)} &  &  &  &  \\
1o.STI\_30\#1o.Has\_Sus\_Efforts &  &  &  &  & 0.000 &  &  &  \\
          &  &  &  &  & {(}0.000{)} &  &  &  \\
Water\_Efforts &  &  &  &  &  & 0.168*** &  &  \\
          &  &  &  &  &  & {(}0.039{)} &  &  \\
C\_or\_S  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 0.202*** &  \\
          &  &  &  &  &  &  & {(}0.066{)} &  \\
C\_or\_S1 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 0.221** \\
          &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & {(}0.100{)} \\
Constant  & 0.054*** & 0.029*** & -0.001 & -0.002 & 0.000 & -0.001 & 0.000 & 0.000 \\
          & {(}0.010{)} & {(}0.008{)} & {(}0.003{)} & {(}0.003{)} & {(}0.003{)} & {(}0.003{)} & {(}0.000{)} & {(}0.000{)} \\
\midrule
Observations & {566} & {555} & {552} & {552} & {552} & {552} & {252} & {140} \\
Year FE      & {No} & {No} & {No} & {No} & {No} & {No} & {No} & {No} \\
No.\ of obs  & {566} & {555} & {552} & {552} & {552} & {552} & {252} & {140} \\
Adjusted\ R\textsuperscript{2} & {0.0696} & {0.211} & {0.233} & {0.232} & {0.234} & {0.275} & {0.199} & {0.133} \\ 
\bottomrule
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{9}{c}{Robust standard errors in parentheses} \\
\multicolumn{9}{c}{$^{***}\ p<0.01$; $^{**}\ p<0.05$; $^{*}\ p<0.1$} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(source code is based on your previous question [my toprule and bottomrule width are different?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/468394/36296) because this one was more complete and compilable)

Comment: nice explanation (+1)! i would consider problems with parenthesis as bug, since if you reserved space for them with `table-space-text-pre  = (` and `table-space-text-post  = )` when necessary, than warning about overfull of `\hbox` should not have a reason to appear.

Comment: @Zarko I was thinking about this since yesterday and was totally confused why the pre and post space did not fix this overfull box. Now I think the problem is that without the `{}` the `()` are considered part of the number and the pre and  post space does not influence the space for the number itself.